# Laravel 6 import GeoJson to mariadb 10.3

Tags: laravel, import, eloquent, mariadb, geojson

i try to import a geojson file to mariadb but without success.
i have install "grimzy/laravel-mysql-spatial": "^3.0"

In mariadb 10.3 i have a table with fiel call geometry which is a multipolygon type.

i put my geojson file into storage folder with this contains :

{
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates" : [
                    [
                        [
                            [ -0.1102826359, 46.0408417066 ],
                            [ -0.1105248307, 46.0396563022 ],
                            [ -0.1110213611, 46.0388036639 ],
                            [ -0.1129798062, 46.0362094235 ],
                            [ -0.1163671451, 46.03141209 ],
                            [ -0.1169999535, 46.0306611122 ],
                            [ -0.1223431941, 46.0274210917 ],
                            [ -0.127828108, 46.02738696 ],
                            [ -0.131955472, 46.0263239776 ],
                            [ -0.1327192268, 46.0260820678 ],
                            [ -0.1341111631, 46.0254217424 ],
                            [ -0.1364125327, 46.0221533793 ],
                            [ -0.1366312892, 46.0211352721 ],
                            [ -0.1364355706, 46.0196546077 ],
                            [ -0.137559152, 46.0144992523 ],
                            [ -0.1406447432, 46.0112045517 ],
                            [ -0.1435702916, 46.0073563523 ],
                            [ -0.1448192016, 46.0046802437 ],
                            [ -0.1457237111, 46.0025868528 ],
                            [ -0.1443122335, 46.0023953422 ],
                            [ -0.1424505442, 46.0019288232 ],
                            [ -0.1410560728, 46.0012420393 ],
                            [ -0.1391710932, 45.9993693344 ],
                            [ -0.1373867157, 45.9934546199 ],
                            [ -0.1368442472, 45.9886806546 ],
                            [ -0.1367820943, 45.9872278342 ],
                            [ -0.1338326656, 45.9874915555 ],
                            [ -0.1324892758, 45.9877161822 ],
                            [ -0.1309578675, 45.9886354109 ],
                            [ -0.1282863936, 45.9905603197 ],
                            [ -0.1268777522, 45.9925728562 ],
                            [ -0.1251428694, 45.9941248526 ],
                            [ -0.1234795172, 45.9954125981 ],
                            [ -0.1218545361, 45.9963297687 ],
                            [ -0.1190123082, 45.9975129571 ],
                            [ -0.1173794238, 45.9978823511 ],
                            [ -0.1135347376, 45.998948798 ],
                            [ -0.1140048709, 46.0020224567 ],
                            [ -0.1146495748, 46.0051634093 ],
                            [ -0.1137408096, 46.0057182993 ],
                            [ -0.109439723, 46.0066376261 ],
                            [ -0.1072318555, 46.0058547069 ],
                            [ -0.0989845556, 46.0055742078 ],
                            [ -0.0932577159, 46.0108323641 ],
                            [ -0.0856733123, 46.0115204658 ],
                            [ -0.0849251337, 46.0113020327 ],
                            [ -0.0843106562, 46.0113458021 ],
                            [ -0.0823215103, 46.0126156391 ],
                            [ -0.0786467339, 46.0150135781 ],
                            [ -0.076715267, 46.017573127 ],
                            [ -0.0757766731, 46.0199173397 ],
                            [ -0.0727775177, 46.0234925804 ],
                            [ -0.071824253, 46.0238888133 ],
                            [ -0.0719896303, 46.0246953855 ],
                            [ -0.0731574813, 46.0248051979 ],
                            [ -0.0737503565, 46.0265473059 ],
                            [ -0.0749919333, 46.0283213729 ],
                            [ -0.0773331769, 46.0301160334 ],
                            [ -0.0817461309, 46.0333205399 ],
                            [ -0.087177269, 46.0352688459 ],
                            [ -0.0893528382, 46.0371191573 ],
                            [ -0.0914526844, 46.0392769973 ],
                            [ -0.0950451816, 46.0397647084 ],
                            [ -0.0987452293, 46.0397717385 ],
                            [ -0.1074530256, 46.0397522898 ],
                            [ -0.1095303511, 46.0406740018 ],
                            [ -0.1102826359, 46.0408417066 ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            },

and in my controller i have add :

```
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Point;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Types\Polygon;
use Grimzy\LaravelMysqlSpatial\Eloquent;

 $example = file_get_contents(storage_path('example.json'));
        $data = json_decode($example, true);

$majsigadhe->geometry = DB::raw('MultiPolygonFromText(\'MULTIPOLYGON('.$wkt.'))');
```

But i have an error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de ''MULTIPOLYGON([ [45.5672032582 -0.781746338], [45.5681200944 -0.7807820887], [45' à la ligne 1 (SQL: update

Can you help me please !